# Non-religious "BCE" / "CE" when writing dates: is it correct in Spanish?

Tags: abreviaturas, tiempo

The [list of common abbreviations in Spanish](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/apendices/apendice2.html) includes the following:

```
/* before current era */
a. de C.    antes de Cristo
a. de J. C. antes de Jesucristo
a. J. C.    antes de Jesucristo

/* current era */
A. D.       anno Dómini
d. C.       después de Cristo
d. de C.    después de Cristo
d. de J. C. después de Jesucristo
d. J. C.    después de Jesucristo
```

Mostly equivalent to English BC and AD. So e.g. 227 BC would be "*227 a. C.*" in Spanish, and 1873 AD would be "*1873 d. C.*"; so far so good.

However, I'm not confortable with implicitly mentioning a religious figure when writing dates, and that's why in English I use [Common Era notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Era) instead.

Can I do that in Spanish as well? **Would it be correct if I just replaced BCE/CE for a.C./d.C.?** Or is there some other abbreviation that I should use instead?

Comment: En la lista de abreviaturas del DPD que has enlazado aparece `e. c. → era común` pero no a. e. c.

Comment: @Rotten deberías poner todo eso como una respuesta

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Though the English non-religious abbreviations are occasionally used in Spanish, nativised forms have been developed, to varying degrees of use/familiarity:

```
( antes de la era común  )  2000 a. e. c. | 2018    e. c.  (               era común    )
( antes de la era común  )  2000 a. e. c. | 2018 d. e. c.  ( después de la era común    )
( antes de la era vulgar )  2000 a. e. v. | 2018    e. v.  (               era vulgaris )
( antes de nuestra era   )  2000 a. n. e. | 2018 d. n. e.  ( después de nuestra era     )
```

Example usage:

> Desde hace unos 6000 años, por lo menos, y hasta hace unos 200 años (a partir de **1800 EC**) toda la riqueza.
>
> - [*El Mundo*](http://www.elmundo.es/blogs/elmundo/elporquedelascosas/2014/04/13/por-que-la-energia-solar-es-la-solucion.html) - *¿Por qué la energía solar es la solución al cambio climático y buena económicamente?*

> Pruebas de circuncisión entre los egipcios pueden encontrarse ya en tumbas y otras esculturas de la época del Imperio Antiguo (**2500 a. e. c.**) en adelante.
>
> - [*La historia de los judíos: En busca de las palabras, **1000 A.E.C.** - 1492*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=--wwMJfypMQC&pg=PA2&lpg=PA2&dq="2500+a.+e.+c.")

> **Los Escenios:** [sic] secta judía de la que no se tiene información histórica suficiente no obstante se conoce que, florecieron en los años **150 a.n.e.** hasta el **70 d.n.e.**
>
> - [*El Jesús que nos negaron*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=5VaECgAAQBAJ&pg=PA141&lpg=PA141&dq="150+a.+n.+e.")

> Estas fechas corresponden a finales del período Postclásico temprano (**900–1250 d.n.e.**), cerca de la época en la que entraron en decadencia tanto Chichén Itzá, en Yucatán, como Tula en el centro de México.
>
> - [*El cuarto códice maya*](http://www.mesoweb.com/es/articulos/Coe_etal/El_cuarto_codice.br.pdf)

---

**Fuentes:**

<sup>• https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anno_Domini</sup>
 <sup>• https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antes_de_Cristo</sup>
 <sup>• [https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Era_Común](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Era_Com%C3%BAn)</sup>

Comment: Curiosa la grafía "Escenios" - el libro que enlazas es el único sitio en el que la he visto escrita así, con la "**c**"

Comment: @Rotten sí, parece una errata por la influencia de *escena* etc ([ngrams: *esenios* vs *escenios*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=escenios%2Cesenios&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=21))

Comment: I have never understood the use of common era (or nuestra era) when it is only the Christians who number the years thus. It is currently 1440 AH (Islam) and AM 5779 (Judaism) to name but just two.